# c# winforms with 'AxWindowsMediaPlayer' control following error thrown: "System.NotSupportedException"

Tags: c#, activex, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a window form which has an AxWindowMediaPlayer control on it. On a client computer with Windows 7, when the form is shown, in Form.Designer.cs an exception is thrown on the line:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.mpPlayer)).EndInit();
```

error message: "System.NotSupportedException: Unable to get the window handle for 'AxWindowsMediaPlayer' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported"

The application is build in Visual Studio with .NET 4.0.
I have tried all the solutions I could find on the client computer: "regsvr32 wmp.dll" - the .dll registered succesfully, "bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff" with restart and I still get the same error.
It's the first time I get this error on a client computer, and the application was run succesfully on many others computers (XP, Windows 7).